# Modify checkout step navigation magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, custom, navigation

I'm customizing the checkout process in magento 2 by adding a custom step between Shipping and Payment steps and by adding a checkbox in Shipping step.

***The problem***

When going to checkout page for the first time both my Shipping and Custom steps are selected as shown in the image.

[image: checkout problem]

So there are two questions:

1. How can  i make that only the Shipping step is visible when i go to checkout page for the first time?
2. How can i make that if i select the checkbox that i added in Shipping step, i skip my Custom step (going directly from shipping to payment) but if i do not select the checkbox i go to my Custom step?

***What i have done so far***

I've created the custom step using the documents provided by magento team in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

This is my **Vendor_CustomCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/view/step-view.js**

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
     *
     * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
     * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of the your module directory.
     *
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_CustomCheckout/mystep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),

        /**
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'custom_step',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Direccion de Facturacion',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         */
        navigate: function () {
            this.isVisible(false);
            this.isVisible = false;
        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            // trigger form validation
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('customStepForm.data.validate');
            console.dir(this.isVisible);
            // verify that form data is valid
            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
                var formData = this.source.get('customStepForm');
                // do something with form data
                console.dir(formData);
            }
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

This is my **Vendor_CustomCheckout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<item name="custom-step" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CustomCheckout/js/view/step-view</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CustomCheckout/mystep</item>
    </item>
    <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
    <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
    <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1.5</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
        <item name="custom-step-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- uiComponent is used as a wrapper for form fields (its template will render all children as a list) -->
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
            <!-- the following display area is used in template (see below) -->
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-step-form-fields</item>
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately) -->
                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customStepForm</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customStepForm.name</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Nombre</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>                
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of you, I added the new custom step before and not after the Shipping Information step but I discovered the same behavior. Did you managed to solve it?
2. It should be possible to use the `navigateTo(code, scrollToElement)` function of the `Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator` for this purpose.

   - Actual the `next()` function of the `step-navigator.js` is called in the `setShippingInformation()` function of the `Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js`(which will be called by clicking the Next button).
   - In order to override this function you can copy the whole `shipping.js` file to your custom module and add the following to your custom `checkout_index_index.xml`.

`checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
...
    <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string"><Vendor>_<ModuleName>/js/view/shipping</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
...
</item>
```

If this does work, I suggest you to not override the whole `shipping.js` file, but extending it, like itself extends the `Magento_Ui/js/form/form` (`Component`). Then you should be able to just override the `setShippingInformation()` function.

Comment: For #1. isVisible: ko.observable(false) or isVisible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual( )) worked for me.

Comment: For #1. `isVisible: ko.observable(false)` or `isVisible: ko.observable(!quote.isVirtual( ))` worked for me. #2. Yes, this would actually work by overriding the call to `stepNavigator.next()` in `setShippingInformation()` method. I end up doing it differently though, i created the same billing address fields in the Shipping Step and used them for that so, in my case, i didn't need the extra checkout step.
Sorry for the duplicate, i hit enter accidentally :/

Comment: its not working for me can you explain in brief